# MQTT Protocol Adapter fails to start

Tags: eclipse-hono

The MQTT Protocol Adapter fails to start with the warning message `MemoryBasedConnectionLimitStrategy - Not enough memory` in the log files. What does it explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol adapter cannot allocate enough memory to reliably handle even a small number of connections. Please provide more memory. 
If you want to ignore the warning and still use the protocol adapter with so little memory, you can configure the maximum number of concurrent connections (`hono.mqtt.maxConnections`) (see the [Admin Guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/admin-guide/mqtt-adapter-config/) for details).